# Is it possible to create a repeatable stream of random numbers?

Tags: python

Per [How to generate a repeatable random number sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023660/how-to-generate-a-repeatable-random-number-sequence) it's possible to set the state of the random module such that you can expect the subsequent calls to randint to return the same number.

One limitation I see with this approach is that the state is set at the module level (essentially a global variable) so it seems impossible to create several streams/iterators of random numbers that would be repeatable (but the streams' calls can be interleaved arbitrarily) with the current mechanism. Are there any workarounds/alternatives libraries to that would enable this?

Comment: See this answer in the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9024521/395029

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a repeatable random number sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023660/how-to-generate-a-repeatable-random-number-sequence)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't have to maintain state at the module level -- see the docs for the [`random` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html):

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a
>   hidden instance of the `random.Random` class. You can instantiate your
>   own instances of Random to get generators that don’t share state. This
>   is especially useful for multi-threaded programs, creating a different
>   instance of Random for each thread, and using the `jumpahead()` method
>   to make it likely that the generated sequences seen by each thread
>   don’t overlap.

Answer (score 5):

`random.Random()` is what you're looking for.

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l72

All the `random.*` module-level functions are simply proxies of a shared `Random()` instance that lives at `random._inst`.

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l879

For your situation, all you'd do is instantiate N `random.Random()` instances; they will have independent internal RNG states and can be seeded/consumed without affecting one another.

In fact, I consider it a best practice to create your own `Random()` instances for non-trivial applications, specifically so it can be easily made repeatable if there's a state-dependent bug, etc. Particularly in test suites, this can be invaluable.

Comment: is it also possible with numpy random?