# Platform-independent random state in scikit-learn train_test_split

Tags: python, random, scikit-learn, platform, seed

Does setting a specific random seed (`random_state`) when splitting train/test datasets using scikit-learn produce the same initialization of the random number generator (i.e., produces same pseudo-random numbers) **over different platforms** - for instance, over different cloud computing instances?

Thanks!

Comment: afaik it uses numpy, so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40676205/cross-platform-numpy-random-seed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as `random_state` is equal on all platforms and they are all running the same versions of numpy, you should get the exact same splits.

Since `random_state` is a numpy instance, I think all of scikit-learn's pseudo-random number generators are frozen because numpy froze `RandomState`.

You can check the documentation for `random_state` [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random_state), which as you can see is `numpy.random.RandomState`. You can check numpy's compatibility guarantee [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/legacy.html?highlight=numpy.random.randomstate#numpy.random.RandomState).